Display an image to specific Razor Page
I'm trying to display an image to a login page and only on the login page. I have tried to put the image by adding it this way. See below:
Login.cshtml

<div class="text-center background-logo">
    // Other code goes here
</div>


However it shows like this 
Not the expected behavior. I added the class to the body of the _Layout.cshtml (see below) and it will fill the whole background of the website but it should not reference the image after login user. The code for CSS is as follows:
site.css

.background-logo{
  background-image: url(../img/image.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}


_Layout.cshtml (for reference)

<body class="background-logo">
    <div class="container background-logo">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
</body>


My question is how to set an image to just the login page but to cover the whole background?

If your login page is MVC structure, you can use ViewContext.RouteData.Values to get the specific controller and action name as condition for judgment.
<body class="@((ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() == "Account" && ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString() == "Login") ? "background-logo" : "")">
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
</body>

If you use the default Identity login page with area(Razor Pages structure), you need change like below:
<body class="@((ViewContext.RouteData.Values["area"]?.ToString() == "Identity" && ViewContext.RouteData.Values["page"]?.ToString() == "/Account/Login") ? "background-logo" : "")">
    <div class="container">

        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
</body>

